# Questions about having emulated Wifi EXACTLY match host wifi in android studio

Tags: android, wifi

It seems my use case is INCREDIBLY unique so hopefully, someone out there knows of a solution or workaround. Firtsly I am not developing an app for android so that sets me apart of 99% of folks on here. What I am attempting to do is use an Android emulator to run an app that lets me remote control a lighting software (Onyx by Obsidian for anyone curious). This app is only available on tablets and phones (otherwise I would just run native on desktop but I have dumped hours into workarounds to get that to work and it unfortunately just isn't possible and it seems the developer is dedicated to ONLY supporting tablets and phones which drives me up a wall) I LOVE the flexibility of being able to control settings on a computer as that opens up tons of possibilities for macros and key commands which is the whole reason I went on this quest in the first place.

The issue is for this remote app to work it MUST be connected to the same wifi as the host machine running the lighting software. As far as I can tell the fact that the android emulator creates a virtual network titled "Androidwifi" is what breaks this from working. Every other element of this works exactly the way I wanted it to so it's a shame this one requirement is preventing the intended outcome.

There are a million tutorials covering connecting Android Studio to an android device over wifi for testing/debugging but I can't find even a small bit of information with connecting the emulator to your local wifi network. I have searched and tested for days but this is my last Hail Mary as it seems impossible. If it is in fact impossible is anyone aware of a different app that lets you emulate android OS OR emulate a single app at a time BUT also lets you connect to the same wifi network the host machine is on?

More info: I am running all this on M1 MAX 2021 Macbook Pro. All the specs are the highest possible config apple offered (64 gigs ram, 8tb internal storage, max graphics card config ect) and it runs android studio like a dream. I understand this would probably work way better on PC as Onyx is a PC software but all my other professional work makes the Mac a better choice for workflow and travel. Funnily enough, Onyx DOES make the remote control app available on mac desktop BUT all the features I need require you to turn the phone to landscape which you CAN'T DO in OSX. Have I mentioned I've tried about 20 possible things to get this to work and it makes me want to slam my head into a wall?!

Hopefully, this question makes sense and I hope someone has a solution for this incredibly bizzare usecase I'm attempting to achieve. Sometimes it's the seemingly "simple" things that can't be done but I figured I'd see if any of you had any ideas!

Thanks